# Connecting R to IBM DB2

Tags: r, db2, database-connection

I am trying to connect to DB2 (AS400 System)

```
library(ibmdbR)
driver.name <- "{IBM i Access ODBC Driver}"
db.name <- "DBName"
host.name <- "HostName"
port <- "23"
user.name <-"placeholderForYourUserName"
pwd <- "placeholderForYourPassword"
con.text <- paste("ConnectDb2;DRIVER=",driver.name,
                  ";Database=",db.name,
                  ";Hostname=",host.name,
                  ";Port=",port,
                  ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP",
                  ";UID=", user.name,
                  ";PWD=",pwd,sep="")
# Connect to using a odbc Driver Connection string to a remote database
con <- idaConnect(con.text)
```

I am getting an error message

```
Missing system name needed for connection
```

Can anyone help to resolve it ?

Comment: Are you sure that ibmdbr supports i-series?

Comment: read a comment previously on looking at odbc.ini  `in the /etc/odbc.ini you need the "System" and/or "Name" Parameter.`  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7bc5a135-5b70-407b-8e52-1ad01c701db4

Comment: @mao, Not sure. Please suggest any other package with which I can connect to

Answer (score 0):

I connected to DB sucessfully.

The issue I had was a wrong `db.name`. But it was showing as `missing system name`.
Please check all the parameters in conncetion string. The error description is misleading

After connecting,

`testtab <- idadf(con, "select * from TableName")` helped to extract data